# value error trying to install numpy on windows 8

Tags: python, numpy, pip, windows-8.1

I am trying to set up a python enviorenment on a computer running Windows 8.1. I have installed Python 3.4 successfully, but when I try to install numpy with pip I run in to the following error:

```
raise ValueError<str<list<result.keys<>>>>
ValueError: ['path']
```

In looking around for similar problems I have found and tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/2362877
Taking in to account that I have Visual Studio 2010 installed.

I have also tried running `vcvarsal.bat` to no avail.

I would appreciate any assistance with this issue, and if more information is required just let me know.

Comment: Is that the actual error you get? I mean, with all the `<str<list` ?

Comment: Its just the last two lines of the output from `pip install numpy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows, it is easier to [download the binary installer for `numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy); especially if you have installed Python from the official .msi installer.

Comment: Excellent! I was only using pip because it was the most effective solution I had found when I was using a Mac. But the binaries are working like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why not. You can download the wheel installer from the page.

Comment: Yeah, i got the binary package of NumPy and using wheel i installed that. But, i am pretty much messed up in installing Scrapy. I am using windows 8.1 with python of version 3.3.3. I have Microsoft visual studio installed as well. And, i even tried to set the environment variable after installing Windows SDK(as i went through several other posts and most of them suggested for this solution). I kind of tried a lot of things  but all in vain. Please, suggest me what to do. @BurhanKhalid

Comment: The links to Gohlke's site for the numpy wheels and other downloads are no long working.