# Failing to install numpy on Python 3.4

Tags: python, numpy

I have installed Python 3.4.1 on Windows 8 x64. I'm trying to use pip, which is bundled with Python 3.4, to install [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

```
pip install numpy
```

When doing so I'm getting the following error message:

> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

I have also tried to use an installer, but the only numpy Windows installer for Python 3.4 I have found was a [win32 installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.0b1/numpy-1.9.0b1-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe/download) which fails saying `Python is not found in registry`, probably because I have an x64 Python.

How do I install numpy for Python 3.4? (preferably using pip)

Comment: Dunno about the problem you're getting, but there are 64-bit Windows installers available: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks, I have tried the right installer, it looked as if numpy has been successfully installed, but still when trying to `import numpy`, I get an import error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we had the same error, the full error is (by using [easy_install](http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/easy_install.html)):

> error: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required < Unable to find vcvarsall.bat>.

Therefore on Windows you need to have Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (for python >=3.3).
Note that the latest version (Visual Studios 2013) won't work.
You can download the Express version for free here: [Visual Studio Express](http://www.go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709949)

For additional information check:

- [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)
- [Building lxml for Python 2.7 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047542/building-lxml-for-python-2-7-on-windows/5122521#5122521)

## However

You may encounter the error:

> ValueError: ['path']

See [value error trying to install numpy on windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100329/value-error-trying-to-install-numpy-on-windows-8).

## Therefore the easiest way

1. Download numpy-version.whl from [uci.edu](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
2. pip install numpy-version.whl (in terminal)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just run the numpy module's .exe file available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/

Comment: and it does work for x64...